# Ajax not returning data to server(Django) on some button clicks

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am building a webpage that contains auto-generated buttons using Django. I am using AJAX to update table values according to each button click. When I try to print `request.POST` on the server side it returns the value inconsistently. Sometimes it will, sometimes it won't.

I have tried putting `alert` in the `success` method and each time I click a button the `alert` pops up even though it doesn't return a value.

```html
<button name="date" type="submit" value={{d}} onclick="sendData(event)">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function sendData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST ",
      url: " ",
      data: {
        date: event.target.value,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      },
      success: function(data) {
      },
      failure: function() {
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When the value is not sent, have you checked the console for errors? We need debugging information in order to help you

Comment: there is no error in the console and it gives status 200 Ok

Comment: Then you need to debug your Django code on the server side

Comment: Iam not doing anything heavy on the server side,For starters iam just passing pre calculated dates as context and just printing the request.POST.

Comment: That may well be the case, but given the lack of useful detail in the question all we can do is make guesses about what the problem may be.

Comment: On ther server side i have a calcdate() function  which populates a dictionary with dates according to given conditions and i pass it to the frontend using  `return render(request,'datepicker.html',{'dates':availabe_dates})`
Heres the output for last 2 button clicks 
`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':['jU92rbh6JVtdhIa1WVctmq8sgV30rDllu07pTdkil2OY8pMWPBDY2IuHVhH7Q6TS']}>`
`"POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14188
<QueryDict: {'date': ['2022-01-20'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['jU92rbh6JVtdhIa1WVctmq8sgV30rDllu07pTdkil2OY8pMWPBDY2IuHVhH7Q6TS']}>`
2022-01-20`